# Дефект отображения надписи "Рекомендованный" в знаках

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки, профиль-участника

Надпись "Рекомендованный" закрывает частично прогресс получения знака. Лично для меня это не критично, но на всякий случай я отписал здесь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде бы здесь все правильно, у меня так же